# How to create a separate cloudtrail for each IAM user in AWS S3 buckets using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a case where I need to add `IAM users` dynamically and send their credentials to their emails so that they can login to the `AWS account` and do some operations like creating `vpcs`, `ec2 instances`, `s3 buckets`, `deleting resources` etc.

I also need to check what are the events that they have done in the `AWS account` after logging in using the `IAM username`.

I'm able to create `IAM users` dynamically and send the credentials to user's emails.

I'm stuck at creating a `cloudtrail` for each user separately. The basic idea is to have a separate `cloudtrail` for each user whose events will be logged to it and stored in an `S3 bucket` which has access permission for only specific username.

I have gone through `boto3 cloudtrail`'s [create_trail()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.create_trail) documentation. But didn't find an option where we can specify the user's name for which the cloudtrail should log the events.

Something like **user1_trail**, **user2_trail**, **user3_trail** which will be recording the events from **user1**, **user2**, **user3** accordingly and will be storing in an `S3 bucket` with names like **user1_trails_file**, **user2_trails_file**, **user3_trails_file**.

I was able to filter the `cloudtrail` events based on user name in Cloudtrail section in `AWS console`.

[image: AWS console]

Is there any way to log the events for each user separately in different `cloudtrails` ?

Comment: Many CloudTrail events don't have a physical user. What is the _actual_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @kdgregory I have a set of tasks that every user needs to perform after logging into the account. I need to verify if the user has actually did those tasks and how long it took for him/her to do and basically everything that the user did after logging into the account.

Comment: From that description, it seems that the best solution is to put all of your events into a single bucket and then use an Athena query to extract the ones belonging to a particular user.

Comment: Re your edit: that's the [LookupEvent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_LookupEvents.html) API, which will do a search over the retained events (the ones that aren't bucketed). It can't be used to distribute those events unless you want to write a program. And if you do that, I think a Lambda responding to bucketed events is a better solution.

Comment: So, will the created trail contains latest events too? Will the logs in S3 be updated instantly? When I query the logs on S3 bucket, will I get most recent logs? Is there any such config that I can setup while creating trail in boto3. I haven't found any in boto3 documentation.